# SQLserver Database Synchronization between two servers

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

Currently, I have two database servers (s1 and s2). 
both server contains the same database MyData and data only update on s1.

What I want to do is that I want both databases contains same data all the time in both server.

Could anyone point out the good way to do this without slowing down s1?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Replication

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Server Replication if you need to be able to read the data from S2.  If you don't need to be able to read the data in S2 you can use Log shipping or database mirroring.

If you use database mirroring you can quickly and easily fail over from using s1 as the server to write to and use s2 as the server to write to.

Answer (score 0):

log shipping is another option

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you need to do it programatically but you can use MS Sync Framework. see more in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx